# Is it required to define doNothing()/when() on Objects mocked using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am writing unit tests using JUnit5 and Mockito for a class `Main.java`.

The dependency class `ExternalApi.java` is injected in `Main.java`.

Here is my `MainTest.java`:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MainTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Main main;

    @Mock
    ExternalApi externalApi;

    @Test
    void testAbcMethod() {

    }
}
```

The abc() method in `Main.java` calls `externalApi.doSomething()` which does some stuff.

I don't want this original externalApi method to be called in my test. Do I need to define

```
doNothing().when(externalApi).when(doSomething());
```

or is it just enough to mock `ExternalApi`?

What happens when we don't define what happens when we call a mocked object's methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens when we don't define what happens when we call a mocked object's methods?

Nothing happens. Mocking is enough since it's not the real class/method that is called but the mocked one.

If you had spied on the instance, that would have triggered the real method call. Only then, you'd have thought of using `doNothing` to silence the method behavior.

```js
@Test
public void whenNotDefineBehaviorOnMock_thenCorrect() {
    List mockList = Mockito.mock(ArrayList.class);
    
   // No behavior defined,
    mockList.add("one");
    Mockito.verify(mockList).add("one");
   // Size is still empty
    assertEquals(0, mockList.size());

   // Behavior defined
    Mockito.when(mockList.size()).thenReturn(100);
    assertEquals(100, mockList.size());
}
```